Why Canadians invest in USD ETFs listed in ― Canada, rather than USA?
What are the strengths and weaknesses of ETFs denominated in USD listed on ―
Canadian exchanges vs. American exchanges?
Consider a Canadian, with USD, who intends to invest in a US Treasuries ETF. Why buy SPAY.U — Global X Short-Term U.S. Treasury Premium Yield ETF, or UBIL.U — Global X 0-3 Month U.S. T-Bill ETF? These trade on the Toronto Stock Exchange.
Why not buy BIL ― SPDR® Bloomberg 1-3 Month T-Bill ETF, SGOV― iShares 0-3 Month Treasury Bond ETF?
Both are listed on NYSE ARCA.
Perhaps these Reddit comments answer my questions, but they’re too snippety. Can someone flesh them out?

Better off to use HISU.U or such instead, really anything Canadian listed. SGOV you lose 15% to dividend withholding tax on non registered accounts, that’s a serious number


Aren’t withheld taxes paid in the us deductible on your tax return? Having 15% taxes withheld in a tfsa would be a larger difference.


The main reason to invest in a US-listed ETF as a Canadian is to avoid withholding taxes on US-assets held in an RRSP. US assets held inside a Canadian-listed ETF will get hit with the tax in an RRSP, but if it's US-listed the tax will be reduced.

The U.S. withholding tax rate charged to foreign investors on U.S. dividends is 30%, but this amount is generally reduced to 15% for taxable Canadian investors by a tax treaty between the U.S. and Canada.

Source: Blackrock
A great resource on this is this page on Canadian Couch Potato:

In an RRSP, using US-listed ETFs for foreign equity holdings can bring a significant tax advantage. That’s because these securities are exempt from the usual 15% withholding tax on dividends imposed by the US government. Assuming a 2% yield on US stocks, the tax savings amounts to 0.30%.
In taxable accounts, Canadian-listed ETFs are generally a better choice. US-listed ETFs offer little or no tax advantage, and in cases where there would be a small benefit it’s likely to be outweighed by other considerations, including currency conversion costs and additional record-keeping—more on this below.
In a TFSA or RESP, you should always use Canadian-listed ETFs for foreign equities. US-listed ETFs offer no tax advantage whatsoever, and in some cases they’re significantly less tax-efficient.
Finally, if you use Canadian-listed ETFs for international equities, look for funds that hold the stocks directly rather than through an underlying US-listed ETF. The “wrap” structure imposes a second level of foreign withholding tax that is not recoverable.

However, if you have USD in a brokerage account and you don't want to convert it to CAD, and the ETFs you want to buy in Canada are only in CAD you might prefer to buy similar US-listed ETFs simply to avoid dealing with currency conversions. There are some ETFs in Canada that trade in USD but I don't think they are typically suitable for general investing purposes. For example there's DLR.U.TO, the USD companion to DLR.TO but you probably wouldn't keep money invested in either.

Aren't withholding taxes refundable when you don't actually owe that much at standard rates?

I don't see any indication that the non-resident withholding tax amount is refundable. Submitting a tax return for this to the IRS seems like it'd be a hassle at the very least. Figuring out for yourself what assets in complicated ETFs had tax withholding amounts and how much they were seems like it would be a lot of work. If the amounts aren't high enough to even be taxable, then how much would you be saving here anyway?

What I mean is that, to my understanding, a withholding tax is set at some arbitrary estimated amount of what you'd actually owe, just so the government doesn't have to wait for your actual return (or so they don't risk you failing to declare the withdrawal as income). If it overestimates what you actually end up owing, you'd get the rest back as a refund, and either way it counts towards income tax paid.

But this doesn't happen automatically. You have to file a tax return to get a tax refund.

Well, yes, but for me it's hard to imagine not doing that anyway.

Is this something you've done before? Are you getting enough of a refund to justify the effort of composing and filing a return? Of course, I'm not talking about someone who already has to file a tax return in the US because they are earning a salary while working in the US as a non-resident alien (or has some other US income they need to file for).

To my understanding, in Canada, if you don't file a return, you don't get certain benefits such as the HST rebate or Climate Action Incentive payment. So of course I file.

I am not talking about Canadian tax returns… this discussion was about US tax returns

I'm a bit confused. The question seems to suggest that investing ETFs traded on TSE is more advantageous than investing those traded on NYSE, but your first paragraph seems to suggest that it's better to invest ETFs traded on NYSE.

@xuhdev Because it depends on whether you are investing in U.S.-listed ETFs inside an RRSP, vs. some other kind of account. When a Canadian invests in a U.S.-listed ETF, the only scenario when there is no U.S. withholding tax on U.S. income from the ETF is when held inside an RRSP. If the ETF is held in any other kind of account (whether plain taxable brokerage account, TFSA, RESP, etc.), then you have to pay U.S. withholding taxes on U.S. income from the ETF. It's like that because RRSP accounts benefit from a pre-existing tax treaty between the U.S. and Canada.

There is still US withholding tax when the asset is held in an RRSP, it's just reduced significantly under the tax treaty between Canada and the US.
